# Return properties of a path that has been matched in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a snippet that works fine:

```
MATCH p=(:Person)-[*]->(:Person)
WHERE 1 < REDUCE(s = 0, x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x.some_var = '1' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END)
WITH p
RETURN p;
```

This returns the path where there are 2 or more instances of `some_var`. No problem.

But how can I get access to some of the properties of `p`?

Say for example, each node has a `node_id` property. I'd like a table of all of these for each node in `p`.

I want something like the above code but ending with:

```
...  
RETURN p.node_id;
```

even though I know that's totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract` to extract those properties from the path, for eg :

```
MATCH p=(:Person)-[*]->(:Person)
WHERE 1 < REDUCE(s = 0, x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x.some_var = '1' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END)
WITH p
RETURN p, extract(x IN nodes(p) | x.node_id) as nodeIds;
```

Or a shorter version :

```
MATCH p=(:Person)-[*]->(:Person)
WHERE 1 < REDUCE(s = 0, x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x.some_var = '1' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END)
WITH p
RETURN p, [x IN nodes(p) | x.node_id] as nodeIds;
```